# Get the number of counts from a Gaussian that fits the logarithm of counts

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, fitting

I have n data to fit:
$$x=[\text{channel}_1,\text{channel}_2,\dots,\text{channel}_n]$$
$$y=[\ln(\text{count}_{1}),\ln(\text{count}_{2}), \dots,\ln(\text{count}_{n})]$$
I'm considering a spectral peak which I'm fitting with a gaussian.
$$
\ \ln[\text{counts}(x)] = \frac{N} {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \,.
$$
So I obtained the parameters $N,\mu,\sigma$. I want to estimate all the counts under the peak, but N now is not the number I'm looking for because there is the logarithm transformation.

- I don't know how to do, maybe I have to solve the integral:
  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Exp\left[\frac{N} {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \right]= ? $$

> Can I do some operations directly on N?

Comment: Fitting the natural exponent of both sides of the equation will of course remove the natural log for counts, but is that possible with the software you are using?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish, but I can tell you that no matter what value of $N$ you use, your integral will diverge to infinity, so that can't possibly be a correct approach.  Could you elaborate on what it means to "fit" these (x,y) data in this circumstance?